# On the rainbow connection number of graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a nontrivial connected graph on which is defined a
coloring $c : E(G) \to \{1, 2,\ldots , k\}$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$ of the edges of $G$, where adjacent
edges may be colored the same. A path in $G$ is called a rainbow path if no
two edges of it are colored the same. $G$ is rainbow connected if $G$ contains
a rainbow $u − v$ path for every two vertices $u$ and $v$ in it. The minimum $k$
for which there exists such a $k$-edge coloring is called the rainbow connection
number of G, denoted by $rc(G)$.

My question is that:

Let G be a connected graph on $n \geq 3$ vertices. Is $rc(G)\geq n_i (G)?$

where $n_i(G)$ denotes the number of vertices of
$G$ which have degree $i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n − 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In full generality, no. A good way to see this is to find a graph where every path only has 1 edge to colour. Thus this fails for complete graphs where you make every edge get the same colour. $rc(K_n) = 1$, but $n_{n-1}(K_n) = n$.

If $G$ has two or more edges (so $G$ is not $K_1$ or $K_2)$, then it's always true for at least one $i$. By the pigeonhole principle and the fact that $rc(G) \geq 1$ (you always need at least one colour for a graph with any edges), there must be *some* $i$ for which it is true, as there are $n \geq 3$ vertices getting $n-1 \geq 2$ degrees, so some degrees must have less than $2$ vertices assigned to them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and exact explanation.